# Integrating AppLozic chat plugin for an angular5 project

Tags: angular, typescript, applozic

I was trying to integrate a third party chat plugin to my angular 5 project but having a very hard time doing it. I could not get what their documentation wants to say or how to carry on it. If anyone has integrated it before then please help me!
[Here is the npm Appklozic link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/applozic) if you want to see the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hence there are no @types for Applozic chat, there are two ways to integrate with angular 2+.

1. Write a typings for Applozic, which is very time consuming and need to know all the functions of applozic
2. Use applozic.js and implement their function, which is how i did it.

### STEPS:

- Run : `npm install applozic`.
- Add `applozic.js` in `angular.cli.json` file.
- declare Applozic: any; in your typings.d.ts file.
- Now you can import applozic in app component and call the init function 
  reference to it.

  ```
  import * as AppLozic from 'applozic';

  AppLozic.init({{appId: 'PUT_APPLICATION_KEY_HERE', userId: 'PUT_USERID_HERE', userName: 'PUT_USER_DISPLAYNAME_HERE'});
  ```